# Browser is caching even when forced not to

Tags: php, caching

I have a strage behaviour I cannot explain with an app I am working on. In the bootstrap of the app I do something like this:

```
  try {
     // db connection and 3rd party services availability checks
  } catch (Exception $ex) {
     // here I will put all sorts of headers meant to disable caching on the client
     header("Content-Type: application/json");
     header("Expires: on, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
     header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
     header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
     header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
     header("Pragma: no-cache");
     die("the app is dead!");
  }
```

If I, for instance, stop the DB myself, the app will halt and print `the app is dead!`. Fair enough, that's what it is supposed to do.

Problem is, when I restart the DB, the weird behaviour shows up: basically the browser will show a working page of the app (home page, login page etc.) but then, when hitting f5 to referesh the page, the error page will sometimes still shows up in a very **intermittent way** (1st f5: it shows, 2nd f5: I get the normal page, 3rd f5: it shows again etc.).

That is clearly a cached version of the page when the DB was not working but I cannot understand why the browser is caching as I told it not to (see all the `header()`).

Comment: Are you 100% sure this is caused by caching? Maybe send a timestamp along with `the app is dead!` to exclude the possibility that it's the DB going down *again*. What kinds of headers does the app send regularly?

Comment: I have a feeling this is not related to caching.  Can you try encapsulating the db connection / 3rd party services in an if statement that prints out a statement if everything runs as it should?

Comment: @Pekka웃 The db does not down again as it is my local one. If I clear the browser cache it works fine and the funny behaviour does not appear.

Comment: Ok so ... update. It's mongodb being a total tos*er! If I make the app fail by stopping mysql (which I also use) the error message appears but as soon as I reastart it all works fine again. With mongo it is different. I stop it, and then when restarted it still throws exceptions every now and again... and then, after 10 refreshes, it restart working continuosuly. It's ridiculous. Does it have to warm up or something? Haha

Answer (score 0):

Some other exceptions are being thrown under circumstances your code doesn't handle gracefully.  Examine each call in the `try` block, read the documentation on it and make sure you are handling the exceptions it may throw.

In general, a big `try` block with a bunch of calls to different subsystems with just one `except` block that assumes there's only one failure mode is a bad idea.  Try having multiple `except` blocks that each catch different exceptions and make the generic handler at the end include the actual exception that was caught in it's output (as a comment in the HTML if you don't want to alarm users).